# Dropbox ext4 on a hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, dropbox, ext4

Dropbox asks me to change the file system of my drive to ext4. 
I am using an UBUNTU machine with two hard drives, a 260GB and a 1TB.
UBUNTU is installed and boot on the 260GB.

I formatted the 1TB to ext4 using mkfs.ext4 and then mounted it in a folder in my root folder:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /DATA/
```

However, Dropbox still does not permit me to use this folder for synchronizing and gives the error of incompatibility with ext4 filesystem.

What's going wrong?